# How to get client host IP by means of utmp

Tags: linux, python

My question is pretty simple: how to get client host IP by means of utmp (who am i)?

Well. Several weeks ago for connecting from my laptop to the remote server I used such command:

```
ssh username@remotehost
```

There was no any issues with retrieving IP of my laptop my means of utmp. I used python and its pyutmp library on the remote and it worked quite well.

But today I have to use another command:

```
 ssh -A -t username@proxyhost ssh -A username@remotehost
```

If I'll use utmp on the remotehost it will return proxyhost IP. But I need to get IP of my laptop.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -A -t username@proxyhost 'export MY_REAL_IP=$SSH_CLIENT; ssh -A username@remotehost'
```

you will have your IP as `$MY_REAL_IP` in the `remotehost`'s ENV

edit:

Sorry, I didn't mean to get into more specifics. the basic idea is to pass variables onwards, how is just the details. you can try something like this for example :

```
ssh proxyhost 'ssh remotehost "export prev_ssh_client=\"$SSH_CLIENT\";env|grep prev_ssh_client"'
```

to avoid modifying the ssh configs

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But how I could define "export MY_REAL_IP=$SSH_CLIENT" in the ssh_config? Actually I'm not running this long command but just a short one and by means of ssh_config ssh redirects me to the right destination.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me. $MY_REAL_IP -- empty value on the remotehost.

Comment: @AndreyTykhonov: The default settings in `sshd_config` prevent passing environment variables into the `ssh` session. See `man sshd_config` and `man ssh_config`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: so proxy and remotehost should be reconfigured to allow passing environment variables, right?

Comment: @AndreyTykhonov: I believe only the remotehost.